# Determinant of projection matrix question

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, projection, projection-matrices

Suppose $P$ is the projection matrix onto the column space of $A$. Then
$$
P = A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T
\quad\text{and}\quad
PA=A
$$
However, taking determinants of this equation gives
$$
\det(PA)=\det(P) \det(A) = \det(A)
$$

Assuming A is invertible this seems to imply $\det(P)=1$, although I know it should be 0. Can anyone point out my mistake please?

Comment: If A is invertible, then its column space is all of $\mathbb R^n$. It means that $P$ is the identity matrix, which has indeed determinant 1.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! So the problem is det(A) will be zero for any A you’d want to project onto. Many thanks!